# __doPostBack doesn't fire on the first click

Tags: javascript

Just like the title says. I have some javascript on a page that is supposed to fire a __doPostBack call if other variables/conditions on the form are valid.

```
function DoPostBack() { 
    var valid = true;
    if (SomethingHappens) { 
        valid = false 
    }

    alert("Is_Valid? " + valid) //evaluates to  true
    if (valid) { 
       __doPostBack("btnSubmit",''); //First click here does nothing, despite it being it by code. Works fine the second time. 
    }
```

And that is hooked up to a button as follows:

```
<input ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="DoPostBack();" type="button" value="Submit"  style="width:80px"/>
```

What is causing the first click of the submit button to be ignored? I have confirmed that this is the behavior I am seeing by placing a breakpoint in my page_load event. The first time __doPostBack is called, the breakpoint is not hit, the second time, it is hit.

Comment: your `alert(Is_Valid...)` is mission quotes, other then that I see no problems with your code. I've tried it out and it works here, see my code at [nomorepasting.com](http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=39640)

Comment: Consider instead of `__doPostBack("btnSubmit",'');` using `document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();`. Also, are you doing `return false` at the end of `function DoPostBack()` to prevent default action? And is spelling "Function" with capital "F" a typo or do you have it like this in code?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is correct, your function should get executed, since it is not, then at least something you have said is not true.